# How to stop a storyboard with RepeatBehaviour="Forever"

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, storyboard

I have a Storyboard in XAML with `ReapeatBehaviour="Forever"`. I run the storyboard when uploading files, which can vary quite a bit in size. I can stop the storyboard no problem when the file upload is complete, but what I'd like to do is run the storyboard just one more time, rather than stopping it midflow by calling `Storyboard.Stop()`.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah sussed it - instead of calling `Storyboard.Stop()`, change the RepeatBehaviour property instead:

```
Storyboard11.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(1.0);
```